# How can I subtract a length of time from a datetime in PHP?

Tags: php, date

Suppose that I have datetime like `2013-01-16-0900`. How can I subtract a length of time - say, 30 minutes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will subtract 30 minutes from the supplied timestamp.

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d-Hi', strtotime( $timestamp ) - 30 * 60 );
```

`$timestamp = '2013-01-16-0900'` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Is it stored as a string exactly like you posted, or is it actually a unix timestamp? If it's a string you can run `strtotime` on it then subtract `1800` (seconds) from it, and then convert it back with `date()`. That would probably be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong preference towards using PHP's built in [DateTime Module](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and adding or subtracting time using PHP's built in [DateInterval Module](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). This allows you to perform reasonably complex date/time math and still respect the rules of time.

Also of note is [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Example Time

```
$dt = new DateTime("2013-01-16-0900", new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
$dt->setTimeZone("America/New_York");
$dt->sub(new DateInterval("PT30M"));
print $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

There is a bit of a learning curve to assembling time interval strings but once you figure it out, you should be able to write a re-usable function.